# How to verify that files are updated with the current version with Maven?

Tags: maven

In a Maven project I have a document called `documentation.md`.

That file should always contain a version string that shows which version of the software the documentation is for:

```
# Title

Version: 1.2.3

....
```

How can I make Maven check for this version string (`Version: 1.2.3`) in the file `documentation.md`, and verify that it is the same as the version of the artifact in `pom.xml`, and fail the build otherwise?

#### Details and notes

- Ideally the check should only run when building a non-snapshot version.
- It's okay to check for any occurrence of the version string in `documentation.md`. The check doesn't need to verify the location of the version string in the file.
- The solution must be a check of `documentation.md` that fails the build if the string is not present. It's not acceptable in my case to update `documentation.md` with the current project version automatically.

Comment: Good start for reading is https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: @Jens Filtering using the Resources plugin can be used to fill in a variable in a resource file. But as far as I know it can't be used to check a file and fail the build if a string is not present. If this can be achieved with the Resource plugin, can you please give me a pointer to how?

Comment: Why not add a variable to the doc and set it while building? So you can make sure it is always set

Comment: @Jens: That's not the requirement in my situation, unfortunately. It has to be a check during the build. The version string in the file has to be manually updated.

Comment: Is the version of your pom file not related to version in your docs?

Comment: @khmarbaise The versions in the pom and in the documentation should be manually updated to be the same at the time of release. The motivation I've been given is that this check should serve as a reminder to update the content of the documentation file before release. If the version in the documentation file is updated automatically then there is a risk that it looks like the contents of the documentation files has been updated but in reality the contents are old and invalid. Having a human confirm that the contents are up to date by updating the documentation version is the requirement.

Comment: Why two places manually maintained? Why not using a single source of truth... the version of the pom ... and put that into the documentation as well ? ... The outdating of content in a docs should be part of a review process..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the [Maven Enforcer plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/evaluateBeanshell.html) has the option to run arbitrary [BeanShell](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell/) code to perform a check.

Using BeanShell it is possible to check the contents of a file using regex.

This seems to be very useful functionality for a log of things!

The Enforcer configuration in the `build` section of the pom file looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>docs-contains-version</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <!-- Checks that all .md files in the documentation dir contains the version string. -->
                    <evaluateBeanshell>
                        <message>Dokument did not contain correct version string.</message>
                        <condition>if ("${skipDocVersionCheck}".equals("true")) {
                                print("[INFO] Skipping documentation version check.");
                                return true;
                            }
                            if ("${project.version}".endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
                                return true;
                            }
                            List files = org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.getFileNames(new File("."), "documentation/*.md", null, true);
                            for (file : files) {
                                if (!org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.fileRead(file).matches(".*^Version: ${project.version}$.*")) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                            return true;</condition>
                    </evaluateBeanshell>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This [blog](https://ngeor.com/2017/04/17/validate-filename-conventions-with-maven-enforcer-plugin.html) gave me valuable clues.